# Elasticsearch why my query matching too slow?

Tags: elasticsearch

So i made indice like this(via python, language not important just want to see mapping scheme);

```
def index_create(es, index_name):
# create an empty index with the defined mapping - no documents added
if not es.indices.exists(index_name):
    # define the mapping
    mapping = {
        "settings": {
           "number_of_shards": 500,
             "number_of_replicas": 0,
             "auto_expand_replicas": False
         },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "firstquery": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "secondquery": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    res = es.indices.create(
        index=index_name,
        body=mapping
    )
```

And i did import all my database just like that into this indice.Size around 530gb and 3.7billion entry only firstquery&secondquery.I have only one indices with 500 shards.But searching way too slow like 30-40seconds(for first request), i thought it needs to be way faster with keyword matching but its not.

I am always sending firstquery for searching and expecting second query to match.This is my template

```
query_body = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "firstquery": "SOMETHING",
        }
    },
}


result = elastic_client.search(index="_all", body=query_body)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? How can i improve ? I have read a lot about elasticsearch pretty surethis needs to be atleast below then 0.5seconds.Because I already tried with mysql or even with tree algorithm & linux grep command results was max 2-5 second.

Additional Information;

1. 32gb ram, 20gb heap locked true
2. x8 core
3. shards 500
4. no replica in indice

This is way too important to me I will answer everything you guys want.Please forgive my english level ..

Comment: 500 shards is too much for your single node cluster, try to use less shards,  20 or 10, which would give you a shard size between 25 and 50 GB, you can use the [shrink api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shrink-index.html) to reduce the number of shards without neededing to reindex everything, also, take a look at this [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) by elastic.

Comment: @leandrojmp just did what you told me on like 400m(40gb json, shard 2), results was like 0.01-0.1 which is awesome.Will update this if works on main database thanks for suggest.